29" by 2.1 tires on a 700c by 40 rim/wheels
i have a hybrid gt transeo comp bike that came stock with 700c by 40mm wheels (and tires), i found them too thin and prone to pinch flats, my question would be if it would be possible to buy 29" by 2.1 tires and tubes and install them in my current rims? or im  eighter stuck with gravel sized tires or having to buy a whole new set of wheels and tires

Pinch flats can be prevented by proper tyre pressure. You have to consider the inner width of your rim and the clearance of your frame and fork.

Welcome to the site - this is such a common question we have a "standard" answer, so this will be closed as a duplicate.  Don't take it personally please.

Basically if it fits without rub, and has enough clearance for slack and flex then probably fine.  If you already have access to a tyre like that, a test fit is probably the quickest way to be sure.
